# Django: reuse code for redirection on missing object

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a site whose URLs look like

> http://www.example.com/NY-2010/
>
> http://www.example.com/NY-2010/location/
>
> http://www.example.com/NY-2010/something-else/
>
> http://www.example.com/Washington-2009/
>
> http://www.example.com/Washington-2009/location/
>
> http://www.example.com/Washington-2009/something-else/

and so on. There are various pages (like location) for various editions (like NY). I use URLconfs like

```
url(r'^(?P<edition>[\d]+\-[\w]+)/$', views.home),
url(r'^(?P<edition>[\d]+\-[\w]+)/location/$', views.location),
```

In each of the views I have to fetch the current edition. The fact is, if the edition name is wrong, I want to redirect to the latest edition. So I do something like

```
def home(request, edition):
    try:
        event = Edition.objects.get(name=edition)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return redirect(home, edition=Edition.latest())
    # If event was found I go on here

def location(request, edition):
    try:
        event = Edition.objects.get(name=edition)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return redirect(home, edition=Edition.latest())
    # If event was found I go on here
```

and so on. Of course there is some duplication that I'd like to minimize. I can think of two ways:

- use `get_objects_or_404()` and customize the 404 view, or
- abstract the common part in a function.

The problem with both ways is that they do not allow me to do a proper redirect, that is, the URL will remain the same even if the view was changed. Is there a better way to handle these redirects?

**EDIT** It seems my question is not clear. In particular it is not clear what I mean by abstract the common part in a function. So, what I **could** do is the following

```
def get_edition_or_current(edition):
    try:
        event = Edition.objects.get(name=edition)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        event = Edition.latest()
    return event

def home(request, edition):
    event = get_edition_or_current(edition)
    # I go on with a valid event here

def location(request, edition):
    event = get_edition_or_current(edition)
    # I go on with a valid event here
```

In this way I can display the view for a proper event, but I cannot change the URL. To change the URL, the view must return a redirect. I cannot set the return value for the view from inside `get_edition_or_current`.

So, how does Django implements `get_object_or_404`? Well, it is simple, it raises an Http404 exception, and catches it later. But of course this only works for Http404 exceptions, because Django is instructed to catch them.

Comment: "abstract the common part in a function"?  Why wouldn't you do this?  Customizing the 404 view would include all the duplicated logic, wouldn't it?

Comment: To change the URL I have to return a redirect in the view. If I called `someFunction()`, I cannot return a redirect from inside `someFunction()`. I would have to check the return value of it, and in case manually return a redirect, which is not much better than what I do now.

Comment: @Andrea: "If I called someFunction(), I cannot return a redirect from inside someFunction()"?  Okay.  I'm baffled about what "duplication" you think you can eliminate through "abstract the common part in a function".  Now you're saying you can't do this?  But in the question you said you could?  Please clarify.

Comment: I could eliminate duplication, for instance by retrieving the latest edition if the given one is missing. But I would not be able to send a redirect. The difference would be that the URL would not change.

Comment: @Andrea: Please post code. Please **update** the question to show how this "abstract the common part in a function" would not work.  If it would not work, why do you have it as a possible solution?  You've posted the same confusing explanation twice.

Comment: I have updated my question. I hope now it is more clear. The reason why I suggested these two solutions is that they are **partial** solutions. That is, they allow me to display a proper view, but not to send a redirect request.

Comment: @Andrea: If the refactor cannot be made to work, then it is not a solution.  A partial solution is the same as no solution.  I'm really confused by why you've included a bunch of non-solutions.  Why isn't the `location` just another parsed parameter from the URL?  If all of these "location" functions are nearly identical, why isn't there just one view function?

Comment: The functions are actually different, and there is not just location, there are many more. I did not include the body of the functions, as it is not relevant to the problem at hand (abstract the first sanity check). The reason I included examples of not working solutions was to avoid that people posted them. I was trying to show how the naives approaches would not work. Anyway, I finally found a solution: see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way to do this would be to create new utility function called `get_object_or_redirect` in the same vein as `get_object_or_404`.  You could probably even copy the contents of `get_object_or_404` from django.shortcuts as a starting point for your implementation, or just extract out what you have above.

EDIT: as noted in the comments, a redirect cannot be done via raising an "exception," so this really can't work the same as get_object_or_404.

Comment: The problem is that get_object_or_404 is based on exceptions, and I'm not sure this is the right way to go. Where should I catch the exceptions I raise? Django automatically catches Http404 exceptions, but that is a particular case.

Comment: Here's an interesting discussion on this:  http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/2d53733b57202dc2/bb9682d1dd5fe5dd?#bb9682d1dd5fe5dd

Comment: I'm not sure if this has changed, but it seems to be django's stance that a redirect is not "exceptional" so there is no HttpRedirectException - you have to return an HttpRedirect from the view.  I wonder if you could define your own redirect exception, and then handle in in a custom middleware class that processes the HTTP response.  middleware is actually not too hard to implement, but I've never tried to deal with exceptions, etc.  Another thought would be to implement a middleware to handle a 404 error coming from the view method and do the redirect there.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting link. I have found a possible solution, but it feels like a hack. I may follow the ideas posted there.

Answer (score 1):

After some more thought, I have found a solution. It is enough to

- use `get_object_or_404`
- customize the 404 view, but **not** directly set it to the desired view. Rather, set it to a view which will send a redirect to the correct view.

Example

```
handler404 = views.error404

# Inside views

def error404(request):
    return redirect(...)
```

Comment: +1 - I think using handler404 is probably the best solution to your problem.  Also +1 for your question - it was interesting to read about it!

Comment: Thank you. After all I accepted your answer thanks to the interesting link for implementing Http exceptions with some middleware. I'm not sure which solution I will end up using, but it is certainly a nice read.